# To merge multiple rows with top row in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I imported a dataframe from word to python using pandas and the dataframe loaded incorrectly.
I want to merge all rows with a NaN value in Diagnosis with the top row that has a value in Diagnosis.

I used this to try and group them but only the first line of each row is visible

```
(df.groupby((df['Diagnosis'] != 'NaN').cumsum())
    .agg(dict(dict.fromkeys(df,'first') ))
    )
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]
Please suggest how to fix this to show all rows relevant to each diagnosis

Comment: If you have real NaNs: `df.groupby(df['Diagnosis'].notna().cumsum())`